# My vb 2003 code can't compile

Tags: vb.net

This is my first post. Please forgive me for asking a basic question as I'm new to programming.

I have following code and it just didn't compile

> ```
>  Module Module1
>
>      Public Sub Test
>
>          dim a as New TestClass() 
>          dim b as string
>          b = a.ReturnString()
>
>      End Sub
>
>  End Module
>
> Public Class TestClass
>
>      Public Function ReturnString() as string
>          Return "Hello World"
>      End Function
> End Class
> ```

EDIT: problem solved

Lesson: Need to instantiate class before using it, many thanks to Gens and all of you!

Comment: What compiler error do you get? It looks like you didn't copy and paste your code *exactly* from your IDE, as the capitalization is incorrect. VB.NET would have auto-corrected that.

Comment: You can still paste the error you know.

Comment: I didn't realize you were using a command line compiler. You're missing the entry point of the app, then. A `Shared Sub Main()`. All of this is created automatically if you're using Visual Studio's templates, but you have to write it manually otherwise.

Comment: Rename "Test" to "Main".

Comment: @David, you need to instantiate the class before use. Check my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your TestClass need to be instantiated before use. To instantiate a class, use **new** keyword before the class name

> dim a as **new** TestClass()
>
> dim b as string
>
> b = a.ReturnString()

Answer (score 2):

You have 2 `End Class` statements, remove one.

Comment: +1, @Bala in that case the `End Class` would need to be on a different line at least

Comment: @JaredPar oh yeah forgot that about vb.net

Comment: still cannot compile after End Class removed, any suggestion?

Comment: @david, nope, I'm a C# user :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you need to put your `Test` method inside a `Module` in order for it to Compile

```
Module Module1
    Public Sub Test
        dim a as TestClass() 
        dim b as string
        b = a.ReturnString()
    End Sub
End Module

Public Class TestClass

    Public Function ReturnString() as string
        Return "Hello World"
    End Function
End Class
```

**EDIT**

As was pointed out by Blindy, you had double `End Class` statements

Comment: End Class removed, but still can't compile

Comment: I was about to suggest that but I wasn't sure if VB allowed free functions or not; I know the CLR allows them

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this

```
vbc <filename>.vb
```

with

```
Public Class Main

        Shared Sub Main
        Dim main as New Main
        main.Test()
    End Sub

    Public Sub Test
        dim a as New TestClass
        dim b as string
        b = a.ReturnString()
    End Sub

    Public Class TestClass

        Public Function ReturnString() as string
            Return "Hello World"
        End Function
    End Class
End Class
```